# How can i reverse a hex to reversed hex in java?

Tags: java, hex, reverse

I don't know how to convert a hex to reversed hex in java like the follow example :
e905c878  -> 78c805e9

I saw a code from another question as below, but i don't know how to make use of it.

```
let hex_string: String = String::from("d59c168e05df4757");
let string_to_bytes = parse_hex(&hex_string);
println!("Hex string as bytes: {:?}", string_to_bytes); //Prints: [213, 
156, 22, 142, 5, 223, 71, 87]
let mut bytes_reversed = Vec::new();
for i in string_to_bytes.iter().rev() {
    bytes_reversed.push(i);
}
println!("Bytes reversed: {:x?}", bytes_reversed); //Prints: [57, 47, 
   df, 5, 8e, 16, 9c, d5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hexString);
```

Reverse pairs of characters:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i += 2) {
  char tmp = sb.charAt(i);
  sb.setCharAt(i, sb.charAt(i+1));
  sb.setCharAt(i+1, tmp);
}
```

Then reverse the whole thing:

```
sb.reverse();
```

Then build:

```
String reversed = sb.toString();
```

As an alternative to reversing the pairs then reversing the string, you could swap the character pairs directly:

```
for (int i = 0, j = sb.length() - 2; i < j; i += 2, j -= 2) {
  for (int d = 0; d < 2; ++d) {
    char tmp = sb.charAt(i + d);
    sb.setCharAt(i + d, sb.charAt(j + d));
    sb.setCharAt(j + d, tmp);
  }
}
```

If you're going to do the alternative, you don't really need to use `StringBuilder`, you could just operate directly on a `char[]`. The only real advantage `StringBuilder` gave was the ability to reverse itself.

---

If the hex is a fixed length (8, in the example you've shown), you can also do:

```
String reversed =
    new StringBuilder(8)
        .append(hexString, 6, 8)
        .append(hexString, 4, 6)
        .append(hexString, 2, 4)
        .append(hexString, 0, 2)
        .toString();
```